# Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.bigquery.dms.common.exceptions.AgentException: Unable to start tbuild command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, teradata, database-migration, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am trying to migrate a table from teradata to BQ using GCP's Data Transfer functionality. I have following the steps suggested on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/teradata-migration.

A detailed description of the steps is below:

1. The APIs suggested on the aobove  were enabled.
2. A pre-existing GCS bucket, BigQuery DataSet and GCP Service Account was used in this process.
3. Google SDK setup was completed on the device.
4. Google Cloud service account key was set to an environment variable called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
5. BigQuery Data Transfer was set up.
6. Initialized the migration agent

- On the command line, a command to run the jar file was issued, with some particular flags e.g.
  *java -cp C:\migration\tdgssconfig.jar;C:\migration\terajdbc4.jar;C:\migration\mirroring-agent.jar com.google.cloud.bigquery.dms.Agent --initialize*
- When prompted, the required parameters were entered.
- When prompted for a BigQuery Data Transfer Service Resource name was entered using the data transfer config from GCP.
- After entering all the requested parameters, the migration agent creates a configuration file and puts it into the local path provided in the parameters.

7. Run the migration agent

- The following command was executed by using the classpath to the JDBC drivers and path to the configuration file created in the previous initialization step
  e.g.
  *java -cp C:\migration\tdgssconfig.jar;C:\migration\terajdbc4.jar;C:\migration\mirroring-agent.jar com.google.cloud.bigquery.dms.Agent --configuration-file=config.json*

8. At this point, an error was faced which said “Unable to start tbuild command”. Below is a screenshot of the error:

Following steps were taken to try to resolve this error using [steps given here](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Tools-and-Utilities-for-IBM-AIX-Installation-Guide/March-2014/Troubleshooting-the-Installation/Teradata-Parallel-Transporter-Problem-Unable-to-Find-tbuild):

1. Teradata Parallel Transporter was installed using Teradata Tools and Utilities.
2. No bin file was found for the installation.

Below is a screenshot of the error message:
[Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.bigquery.dms.common.exceptions.AgentException: Unable to start tbuild command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3DuP.png)

Comment: Since this appears to be Windows, `C:\Program Files\Teradata\Client\xx.yy\bin` should be the path to `tbuild.exe`, where xx.yy is the version of TTU you installed. BTW - current versions of Teradata JDBC driver do not use `tdgssconfig.jar`

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this, Teradata Tools and Utilities package needs to be installed, it can be found under this [link](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-linux-installation-package-0).

Keep in mind, that TTU (Teradata Tools and Utilities) does not support all OS, full list of supported systems [here](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Tools-and-Utilities-Release-Definition/June-2020/Release-Information/Supported-Teradata-Vantage/Teradata-Database-Versions)